# Idiomatic elixir to execute if params is not nil?

Tags: elixir

How to go about filtering out invalid params like nil or empty list before proceed to process the params?

The `case` use below seems to be common but it's not clear code -- I am pretty sure there is a simpler and idiomatic way to do this.

```
 def load(token) do

   case token do
     nil -> nil
     [] -> nil
     token -> process(token)
   end

 end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a function has several clauses, Elixir will try each clause until it finds one that matches. This allows you to "filter" on the basis of supplied arguments - particularly useful if the functions share no common logic.

```
def load([]), do: IO.puts("empty")
def load(token) when token == nil, do: IO.puts("nil") # Matching `nil' is OK too.
def load(token), do: process(token)
```

The second clause illustrates the use of guards which permit more general matches, there are [a number of predicates that are valid as guards](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#expressions-in-guard-clauses) all of which can be attached to (almost) any expression which are used to switch upon function-arguments, recursively or otherwise.

This convention holds across all of the existing BEAM languages and is useful to keep in mind when reading OTP documentation.

Comment: Right so this is fine too,
``def load(nil), do: IO.puts("nil")``

Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll get a warning that comparing with nil is unsafe. I think you need to use `is_nil()`

Answer (score 10):

I prefer

```
def load(nil), do: nil
def load([]), do: nil
def load(token), do: process(token)
```

You could also do:

```
def load([]), do: nil
def load(token) when not is_nil(token), do: process(token)
def load(_), do: nil
```

But I would not compare `token == nil` because you will get a warning from the compiler.